# Finding a generating set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I want  to solve the following task:

Find the minimal generating set (german: "minimales Erzeugendensystem") for the set S:

S = { $\begin{pmatrix}  1 \\   1 \\ 0 \\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}  0 \\   0 \\ 1 \\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}  0 \\   1 \\ 0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}  1 \\   0\\ 0 \\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}  1 \\   0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$  }

with S in $\mathbb{Q}^5$. A is the matrix with the vectors from S as its columns.

Usually I would just have used the gauss algorithm on the matrix A to achieve the reduced form with only vectors independent from each other left. However, the solution of the exercise looks totally different, and I don't understand what exactly is being done:

The solution says that with the the invertible Matrix W..

$$W =\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 0 & -1/2  & 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

...we arrive with the gauss algorithm at the equation:

W * A = $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1& 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

However it does not say from what we arrive at this matrix W, and why arriving at this equation is useful - and I can't really figure. Any help/hints?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It certainly helps to show the system has rank $4$. I have no idea where $W$ comes from: this  would require the context.

Furthermore, knowing $WA$ helps you extracting a minimal generating set from $S$. Indeed, it amounts to determine which vectors of $S$ can be expressed in function of the others. Note that left multiplying by an invertible matrix preserves linear relations between the column vectors of the matrix $A$, and conversely.

Let's denote $e_1, e_2,\dots,e_5$ the column vectors of $A$, and $e'_1,e'_2,\dots,e'_5$ those of $WA$. We clearly have $e'_5=e'_1+e'_2$, hence $e_5=e_1+e_2$.

Also $e'_1,e'_2,e'_3,e'_4$ are linearly independent, hence  $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ are.

Thus $\;\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ is a basis for $\langle\, S\,\rangle$.

Comment: e_5 = e_1 + e_2 .. ?

Comment: $W$ can be seen as the matrix of an isomorphism $w$, and for all $i$, $w(e_i)=e'_i$. Hence any relation $\;\sum_i\lambda_i e'_i=0$ is simply $w(\sum_i\lambda_i e_i)=0$. Now use the fact that $w$ is injective.